# ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name while installing data miner repository

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, dataminer

I am getting the subjected error while trying to install data miner repository in SQL developer.

after double clickitng the connection in data miner tab as in the below screenshot I followed the following path to install the data miner repository

[image]

step 01

[image]

step 02

[image]

step 03

[image]

step 04

[image]

step 05

[image]

step 06
then it gets the following error.

[image]

```
Error starting at line : 19 in command -
create user ODMRSYS identified by Alxv19x default tablespace &&1 temporary tablespace &&2 quota UNLIMITED on &&1 PASSWORD EXPIRE
Error report -
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
65096. 00000 -  "invalid common user or role name"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create a common user or role with a name
           that was not valid for common users or roles.  In addition to
           the usual rules for user and role names, common user and role
           names must start with C## or c## and consist only of ASCII
           characters.
*Action:   Specify a valid common user or role name.
```

could someone help me please ?

Comment: Are you connecting to CDB? Did you try to connect to a PDB and re-execute these steps? If you create a user on CDB, the username must be prefixed with `C##` to label it as a common user.

Comment: If this is a personal database installed on your machine, re-install it without the container option.  Oracle's "containers" are not what everyone else calls "containers", and to my knowledge very few people use that option in production systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We got the same issue once before, the solution is as follows:

1. go to your sqldeveloper directory.
2. open the dataminer directory.
3. edit the script file named instodmrsyssql.
4. go to the line where exists the following sql query:

`create user ODMRSYS identified by Alxv19x default tablespace &&1 temporary tablespace &&2 quota UNLIMITED on &&1 PASSWORD EXPIRE;`

5. add before the mentioned query the following:

`alter session set "_oracle_script"=true;`

the final result is:

`alter session set "_oracle_script"=true;`

`create user ODMRSYS identified by Alxv19x default tablespace &&1 temporary tablespace &&2 quota UNLIMITED on &&1 PASSWORD EXPIRE;`

6. save it
7. then if you have sqldeveloper already opened, just close it and
   reopen it and re-run the process.